# how to minify files with grunt?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am creating an angular app with grunt/yeoman and trying to create a public version with minified files. The problem is that no js files and css is created:

```
// Generated on 2015-06-01 using generator-angular 0.10.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['app/{,*/}*.js','app/**/*.json'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['app/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          'app/**/*.html',
          'app/**/*.js',
          'app/**/*.json',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          'app/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          'app/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: 'dist'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          'app/scripts_old/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            'dist/{,*/}*',
            '!dist/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['app/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['app/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: 'app/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: 'app/images',
        javascriptsDir: 'app/scripts_old',
        fontsDir: 'app/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: 'dist/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          'dist/scripts_old/{,*/}*.js',
          'dist/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          'dist/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          'dist/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: 'app/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: 'dist',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['dist/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['dist/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['dist/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          'dist',
          'dist/images',
          'dist/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
          js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/styles/main.css': [
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/scripts/scripts.js': [
            'dist/scripts/scripts.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    concat: {
      dist: {}
    },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'app/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: 'dist/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'app/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: 'dist/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'dist',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: 'dist'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: ['*.js', '!oldieshim.js'],
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['dist/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: 'app',
          dest: 'dist',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'modules/**.*.js',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: 'dist/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.',
          src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
          dest: 'dist'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'app/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    protractor: {
      options: {
        keepAlive: true,
        configFile: "test/protractor.conf.js"
      },
      run: {}
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('running grunt serve , value of target',target);
    if (target === 'dist') {
      grunt.log.warn('target = dist');
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'test',
      //'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-protractor-runner");

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    //'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
    //'protractor:run'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    //'useminPrepare',
    //'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    //'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

The directory structure looks like this:

app/modules/ 
styles
commone/**/**/partials

When I run grunt build I get:

```
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'imagemin-gifsicle'
>> Local Npm module "grunt-google-cdn" not found. Is it installed?

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
Cleaning dist/.htaccess...OK
Cleaning dist/404.html...OK
Cleaning dist/bower_components...OK
Cleaning dist/index.html...OK
Cleaning dist/robots.txt...OK

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task

Running "concat:dist" (concat) task

Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
>> No files provided to the ngAnnotate task.

Running "copy:dist" (copy) task
Copied 9 files

Running "cssmin:dist" (cssmin) task
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>> Destination dist/scripts/scripts.js not written because src files were empty.

Running "filerev:dist" (filerev) task

Running "usemin:html" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "usemin:css" (usemin) task
Replaced 0 references to assets

Running "usemin:js" (usemin) task
Replaced 0 references to assets

Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Minified dist/404.html 3.53 kB → 3.39 kB
Minified dist/index.html 1.16 kB → 1.07 kB

Done, without errors.
```

How can I generate css and js files?

Comment: tried running `build` task ?

Comment: I tried that the results of that I listed above

Comment: clearly you can see the reason in you build.

Running "cssmin:dist" (cssmin) task
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>> Destination dist/scripts/scripts.js not written because src files were empty.

Comment: I managed to create some scripts now

Comment: now figuring out how to minify the js

Answer (score 0):

Could you please ensure that you do have correct source file mapped in uglify configuration.As per your current above pasted script the src and destination both files are with same name.

```
uglify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dist/scripts/scripts.js': [
        'dist/scripts/scripts.js'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can go through with [this](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) for more information. Initially try to make it work with simple configuration like this :

```
uglify: {
  dist: {
     files: {'dest/b.js': ['src/bb.js', 'src/bbb.js']}
  }
}
```

How does the htmlmin task work see [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin). and for where are those files located in the dist folder see below

```
htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      conservativeCollapse: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeOptionalTags: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'dist',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: 'dist'
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: how does the htmlmin task work? where are those files located in the dist folder?

Comment: I have updated my original answer based on your comments.Thank you.

Comment: that looks good, another question. If I want to link in my json mockdata files where do I specify this?

Comment: btw the htmlmin does not get all my partials ie html files and minify them into the index.html in dist?